# Remove character in R

Tags: r, character

I have created a third column to concatenate V1 and V2 in this way:

```
dataframe = x
    V1   V2   
[1]          
[2] 2A   3S   
[3] 2A    

x$V3<-paste(x$V1,x$V2,sep=",")
```

I obtain this

```
dataframe = x
    V1   V2   V3
[1]          "character(0),character(0)" 
[2] 2A   3S   2A,3S
[3] 2A        2A,character(0)"
```

How do I remove the word character(0) and the other symbols like "," and " ?

Comment: can you also include the dataframe ie run `dput(x)` and paste the results in your question

Comment: Is indicated as x in the body text :)

Comment: DO not paste it here. paste it in the question. Also that is not the result you obtain when you run `dput(x)`. copy the result of `dput(x)` and edit your question by posting that in there. Not on the comments

Comment: You have not posted the the results of `dput(x)` ie `dput(your_data_frame)`

Comment: run `dput(x)` on your console. Copy the output. it should be something close to `structure(V1 = ....)`. Paste that

Comment: I have waited for you to paste the data but it seems you have an issue. Hope you manage to do that

Answer (score 1):

We can replace the `character(0)` value with empty string when concatenating the two columns:

```r
x$V3 <- gsub("^,|,$", "", paste(ifelse(identical(x$V1, character(0)), " ", x$V1),
                                ifelse(identical(x$V2, character(0)), " ", x$V2),
                                sep=","))
```

Comment: This works but then shows  the word NA rather than character(0))

Answer (score 1):

To avoid getting unwanted symbols/values when combining columns, you can use tidyr function `unite()` and get the desired result. I have attached an example below:

```
x[is.na(x)] <- "" # to remove NAs before combining
new_x <- unite(x, "V3", c("V1", "V2"), sep = " ", remove = FALSE)
```

If your initial table doesn't have the NAs, then you can use followed by `unite()` funcyion:

```
x[x=="character(0)"] <- "NA" # to convert to NA
x[x=="character(0)"] <- "" # to instantly convert to empty string
```

Comment: this says Error in UseMethod("unite") : 
  no applicable method for 'unite' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: @Nnnz when I try to reproduce your example, I have NA in the table, so I have now updated the code and this should work. The first line to replace NA with an empty string and the second one to create a new column when combining the V1 & V2.

Comment: Also, I just updated how you can replace "character(0)" to an empty string and then use unite() function with no issues.